# Using seconds in AVPlayer seekToTime

Tags: ios, avplayer, cmtime

this should be a simple one. I have an `AVPlayer` playing a video file and I want to be able to jump to a specific time but I'm having some trouble understanding how `CMTime` works.

I need to specify the time in seconds. For example: if I wanted to jump to second 10.8 I'd like to do something like this:

```
[self.avPlayer.currentItem seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.8, 1];
```

But I'm not getting the result I want.

Answer (score 25):

http://warrenmoore.net/understanding-cmtime

Might give you a clearer idea of CMTime.

If you changed your line to read...

```
[self.avPlayer.currentItem seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.8, 60000)];
```

You might get better results. The 60000 is how many items make up a single second. If you use 1 for this value then you can only jump to a single place per second - by putting 60000 you are giving yourself 60000 places between second 10 and second 11.

Comment: Thank You!
I finally understand NSTime concept

Comment: can see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803475/play-a-video-in-avplayer-for-a-specific-duration-in-swift3-ios

Answer (score 14):

In case you need to seek to a **very specific time** I would recommend using this method with tolerance:

```
let myTime = CMTime(seconds: 10.8, preferredTimescale: 60000)    
player.seek(to: myTime, toleranceBefore: .zero, toleranceAfter: .zero)
```

Documentation: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1387741-seek). Apple suggests using it for high accuracy.

Comment: after several solutions on this post, I ended needing to use the toleranceBefore and toleranceAfter parameters for the seek to work properly.

Comment: there's no ".zero" in CMTime

Answer (score 3):

Swift version

```
avPlayer.seek(to:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(10.8,1000))
```

Comment: Swift 5.1 version

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.1 version

```
player?.seek(to: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(10.8), timescale: 1000))
```