# 'seek(to:)' was deprecated in iOS 11.0:

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, video, background

Getting this warning:

'seek(to:)' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use -seekToTime:completionHandler:, passing nil for the completionHandler if you don't require notification of completion

written in this particular line of block of code:

```
    @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
        p.seek(to: .zero)
    }
```

Any help with this will be much appreciated

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666190/using-seconds-in-avplayer-seektotime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation you can see that `seek(to:)` has been deprecated. You need to use `seek(to: , completionHandler:)`. If you don't want to use a completion handler, you just pass a `nil`:

`seek(to: .zero, completionHandler: nil)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem